How to implement array contains functionality , in LWC component?
I am quite new to the salesforce development.
Right now I am trying to Iterate over a <tr><td></td></tr> something like this.
        <aura:attribute name="updatingContactIds" type="List" default="[]" />
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactWrappers}" var="wrapper" indexVar="index">
            <tr>

                <td class="contact_status_td">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!wrapper.contact.DBSLStatus__c == null}">

                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.updatingContactMap[wrapper.contact.Id]}">
                        <span class="slds-badge slds-theme_warning dbsl_status_badge processing_status_class">
                            Processing
                            <div class="loader2"></div>
                        </span>
                    </aura:if>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(v.updatingContactMap[wrapper.contact.Id])}">
                        <lightning:button value="{!wrapper.contact.Id}" variant="base" label="Update"
                        class="slds-badge slds-badge-primary dbsl_status_badge"
                        onclick="{!c.singleContactUpdate}"/>
                        <span data-contact-id="{!wrapper.contact.Id}" class="null-status">{!wrapper.contact.DBSLStatus__c}</span>
                    </aura:if>
                </aura:if>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>

Basically I want to check whether the wrapper.contact.id exists in updatingContactMap list.
In my singleContactUpdate
singleContactUpdate: function(component, event, helper){ 
        var contactId = event.getSource().get("v.value");
        console.log('Updating single contact with ID:', contactId);
        var contactIdAr=[];
         var updatingContactMap = component.get("v.updatingContactMap");
        contactIdAr.push(contactId);
        component.set("v.updatingContactMap", contactIdAr);
 }


The code in the question is of Aura component.The answer would remain same
We can use either includes or indexOf JS array method here.
Below code can be used -
    var contactId = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    var updatingContactMap = component.get("v.updatingContactMap");
    const isValueAlreadyPresent = updatingContactMap.includes(contactId);

Generally , indexOf() works much faster than includes() in Chrome.
Also , I see some scope for improvement in your variable naming & controller code.
